# Помогите реализовать

Tags: php

Есть метод в классе, который вернет мне данные в виде объекта, результат в виде объекта возвращается по умолчанию через функцию `fetch_object()`. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
$data = ActiveRecord::('user')->get().
```

Метод `get()` класса `ActiveRecord` вернет все данные из таблицы `user`, в переменной `$data` содержатся данные в виде объекта, которые можно выводить через `foreach`. 
Сама задача, нужно сделать так, чтобы следующая запись

```
$data = ActiveRecord::getInstance('user')->get()->asArray()
```

возвращала уже данные не в виде объекта, а в виде массива. Так вот, чтобы использовать запись вида

```
ActiveRecord::getInstance('user')->get()->asArray()
```

нужно ведь в методе `get()` вернуть сам объект через `return $this`, но тогда как одновременно вернуть сами данные в виде объекта? Сейчас ведь возвращаю

```
return $result
```

Но если возвращать `$result`, то уже не получается обращать к `asArray()` как задумано, через сцепление методов.
http://pastebin.com/QKmftU8i

Comment: А `fetch_object` это также метод класса?

Comment: да, fetch_object это метод класса

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QKmftU8i вот класс, который занимает выборкой данных

Comment: По-моему, достаточно сохранить `ActiveRecord::getInstance('user')->get()` в переменную. А потом можно ей пользоваться просто как объектом и вызывать у неё метод `asArray()`. Другое уже дело, что в `asArray()`, видимо, каждый раз запрос заново делается - это уже к вопросу об оптимизации кода.